# Mysql convert sql to TRANSPOSE sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have quiet interesting task at my university.

I have DB table:

```
----------------------------------------
| id | fee | status       | created_at |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 10  | COMPLAINABLE | 2018-05-01 |
| 2  | 15  | COMPLAINABLE | 2018-05-01 |
| 3  | 18  | COMPLAINABLE | 2018-05-02 |
| 4  | 1   | COMPLAINABLE | 2018-05-03 |
| 5  | 2   | COMPLAINABLE | 2018-05-03 |
----------------------------------------
```

I wrote SQL:

`SELECT created_at AS ts, SUM(fee) AS value 
FROM leads_ads 
WHERE status NOT IN ('COMPLAINED', 'COMPLAIN_ACCEPTED')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY created_at ASC;`

And at first result was fine:

```
-------------------------
| ts           |  value |
-------------------------
| 2018-05-01   |   25   |
| 2018-05-02   |   18   |
| 2018-05-03   |   3    |
-------------------------
```

But now i have to rewrite sql to get result like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    ts0   |value0|    ts1   | value1 | ...... | tsn | valuen |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|2018-05-01|  25  |2018-05-02|   18   | ...... | tsn | valuen |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried many ways to do it but can't fine a right result(tried TRANSPOSE pivot table). So I decided to ask here. maybe someone will push me to the right way.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: 'Interestingly' this is a very frequent question in SO try googling mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article (this shows how you can resolve this with dynamic SQL): http://onlybluefeet.com/2015/01/18/how-to-rotate-rows-into-columns-in-mysql/